# Animating your Facebook Timeline

Tags: facebook, profile, facebook-timeline, animations

Some users have found it's possible on Google Plus to [animate your profile](http://mashable.com/2012/03/01/animate-google-plus-gifs/).

What  I'd like to know is if anyone has found a way to animate your Facebook timeline, through either an animated .gif, a video or .swf file somehow?

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15767/how-do-i-post-animated-gifs-on-facebook or something like the cover photo?

Comment: There is a way to do it now. I'm not quite sure the exact process, but I was able to change only my timeline photo to a gif.

Comment: can you provide ANY details? Did you just upload an animated gif - does it loop, single run, through?

Answer (score 4):

Facebook allows posting animated gifs but stops them from actually being animated programmatically. There are a few apps out there that claim to let you animate your profile, but anyone visiting would need to have that app installed as well to see it.

you can't upload swfs to Facebook, and videos won't autoplay.

I do have to admit, you gave a lot of options, but Facebook has done good work on making sure I'm not thinking I stumbled onto a Myspace profile.

Comment: exactly. Facebook being clean and tidy was the main reason I switched to Facebook in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook doesn't support neither animated GIFs nor video files. Moreover, no self-respecting web service with user-generated content will ever allow SWF files because they're not multimedia but rather executables (i.e. applications) and pose incredible security risk.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to animate your cover which someone has discovered how to with a animated cat with a gun. It's pretty easy to do, but any others I cannot figure out. Ex: https://www.facebook.com/YunodoasIsayMentallyChallengedComputer 
or
https://www.facebook.com/Morganfreemanhascottoncandy